# Why should I use printf for function works fine

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to use Raspberry Pi Pico with C. I am taking data from RFID and trying to get decimal value from byte. I can take decimal value but I have a problem.

I need to read 14 character from RFID, then I need to reverse it because of LSB-MSB thing.

So I found this function:

```c
void reverse1(char *a, int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
        return;

    reverse1(a, start + 1, end - 1);

    char temp = a[start];
    a[start] = a[end];
    a[end] = temp;

    return;
}

char *strrev1(char *s)
{
    reverse1(s, 0, strlen(s) - 1);
    return s;
}
```

```c
unsigned char reversed_card_number[11];
unsigned char reversed_country_number[3];
strcpy(reversed_card_number, strrev1(card_number));
strcpy(reversed_country_number, strrev1(country_number));
printf(strrev1(card_number));
```

If I don't write this line:

```c
printf(strrev1(card_number)) // If I print country_number instead of card_number still reverse function works.
```

`strrev1` doesn't reverse one of the RFID tag, so my decimal value comes incorrect. Why should I have to write this `printf` line?

Comment: Why do you call the reverse function twice, as you already have the reversed card number string you can print, and calling the reverse function twice will reverse it twice so it gives back the original string. Also, the implementation is very inefficient, and does not even relate to electronics, as reversing strings is a pure programming question.

Comment: @Justme one is for country number which has 3 character and the other one is for card number which has 11 character. I could use one reverse for 14 character then substring but I did this way.

Answer (score 4):

Your `strrev1` function modifies its input string.

So, after this line:

```
strcpy(reversed_card_number, strrev1(card_number));
```

both `reversed_card_number` AND `card_number` are reversed.

When you call it again, it gets un-reversed, etc.

Fix: call `strrev1` only once, eg:

```
strcpy(reversed_card_number, card_number);
strrev1(reversed_card_number);
```

Or, if you don't need the original number, you can just reverse that without creating a new variable.

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked.                  strcpy(reversed_card_number, strrev1(card_number)); ,                strrev1(card_number);
 when I use these it is working. I am not good at pointers of something but maybe that is the problem. I need to take 2 reverse card_number and one reverse reversed_card_number .

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot make sure you are not using strrev inside printf, and print the correct variable. Also, I suggest doing some more C language tutorials. You need to get a clearer  notion of variables and pointers to move forward :)